# Joda time parsing time with more than 24 hour

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

Is there possible parse time with date like "2016-07-13T25:50" to get LocalDateTime with value "2016-07-14T01:50"? I want to use only Joda time and java.util.

Comment: You don't want to use JSR-310 which is built in to Java 8?

Comment: Just wondering: where does our requirement come from? And is this only about 25 hours; or would you want to accept 99 minutes as well? Or 343 minutes?

Comment: I can not use java 1.8, because project is written in 1.7.

Comment: Beucase i need to parse 24 hour, which joda time cannot.

Comment: Split the date / time on the T character.  Use a SimpleDateFormat to parse the date.  Parse the time with your very own custom code.  Add the time to the date and use another SimpleDateFormat to produce the output date / time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lenient chronology in Joda-Time:

```
LenientChronology lenientChrono = LenientChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.getInstance());
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm").withChronology(lenientChrono);
LocalDateTime ldt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime("2016-07-13T25:50");
System.out.println("lenient=" + ldt); // 2016-07-14T01:50:00.000
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem possible without writing a custom parser becase Joda and the Java 8 DateTime API (which is largely inspired by Joda) works with the ISO-8601 calendar system and that doesn't allow this format.

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) regarding durations:

> Alternatively, a format for duration based on combined date and time representations may be used by agreement between the communicating parties either in the basic format PYYYYMMDDThhmmss or in the extended format P[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]T[hh]:[mm]:[ss]. For example, the first duration shown above would be "P0003-06-04T12:30:05". However, individual date and time values cannot exceed their moduli (e.g. a value of 13 for the month or 25 for the hour would not be permissible).

A list of available DateTimeFormatters is available in the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).